# Getting an error writing R function with gsub

Tags: r, function, gsub

Tried copying an old working code which substituted 2 values instead of 3. This isn't working though. Here it is:

```
Names <- c("Robert", "Mandy", "Mordecai")



Search <-function(find,relace,type){

gsub("find","relace",type)

}


Search("o","ooo", Names) #getting Names vector but no replacements
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `"`'s from the line with the gsub call. Try:

```
gsub(find,relace,type)
```